# How to handle crossdomain.xml in django?

Tags: django, nginx, crossdomain.xml

I'm running an an ubuntu vm - django is running under apache2 behind nginx

I need to setup crossdomain.xml  - currently getting 'access denied' etc when trying to play flash movs

whats the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try [django-flashpolicies](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-flashpolicies/), which will construct the XML for you. It does serve the crossdomain.xml file via Django, which will be less efficient than serving it statically.

Answer (score 1):

You can let nginx serve the crossdomain.xml for you. you can find an example config [here](http://blog.vokle.com/index.php/2009/06/10/dealing-with-adobe-and-serving-socket-policy-servers-via-nginx-and-10-lines-of-code/).

this is more efficient and site-wide if you like.

Comment: do you have a working link? im trying to figure out how to serve crossdomain.xml via nginx

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is create view in your app where you handle requests from flash:

```
def crossdomain(request, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'crossdomain.xml', {})
```

Put crossdomain.xml in your templates dir, and add  pattern to urls.py:

```
(r'^crossdomain.xml', 'projectname.appname.views.crossdomain')
```

(it's not good for production servers until you use cache over django).